# Bootstrap 3 CSS: Thin white gap above navbar only on mobile in production

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Django + Bootstrap 3 + Heroku. In production, there's a thin white line above the navbar on the mobile viewport. It's there on all pages. On my local machine, it isn't there. I've done sanity checks to make sure they're in sync.

Production: http://screencast.com/t/3Ukg9Lgu34N

Local: http://screencast.com/t/dNVQVtuWgW

I was able to fix it locally by adding .collapse { border: 0 !important; margin-top: 0 !important; }, but for some reason, it doesn't translate to production.

See below for full navbar css. You can view the production site here: http://goo.gl/mwXfRl

Any idea what's going on?

**navbar-static-top.css:**

```
.navbar {
    border: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-static-top {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    background-color: #11C356; /*#649072; #fafafa;*/
    border-color: #11C356;/* #649072; #fafafa; */
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #e4e4e4; /*#0aa647;*/ /*#D5DED9*/
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #11C356;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #11C356;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #f2f2f2; /*#11C356;*/
    line-height: 30px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    /*font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    color: #f2f2f2; /*#11C356;*/
    font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #e4e4e4; /*#0aa647; *//*#D5DED9*/
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    color: #0aa647;
    background-color: #fafafa; /*#11C356*/
}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
float: right!important;
}

.collapse {
    border: 0 !important;
    border-color: #11C356;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this with the following css at the template level:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-style: hidden !important;
```

It's more of a patch, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin-top: -1px` to `navbar-static-top` like this:

```
.navbar-static-top {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -1px;
    background-color: #11C356;
    border-color: #11C356;
    /* border-style: solid; */
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.navbar {
position: relative;
min-height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
/* border: 1px solid transparent; */ or border:none;
}
.navbar-static-top {
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
background-color: #11C356;
/* border-color: #11C356; */
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```